# DataTables column visibility with Responsive extension

Tags: javascript, datatables

I am quite new in jQuery DataTables. I just read about responsive table feature provided by DataTables, see [this example](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/auto.html).

Here columns are hiding on window resizing but the problem is that last column is also hiding. Can we define which column must be hidden on different window sizes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [Class logic](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/classes) for fine-grained control on when each column would be visible.

For example, to always show last column:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#example').DataTable({
       responsive: true,
       columnDefs: [
          targets: -1,
          className: 'all'
       ]
    });
});
```

where [`columnDefs.targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) set to `-1` points to last column (column index counting from the right), and `className: 'all'` indicates that column will always be visible, regardless of the browser width.

Comment: I think this will help me. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you can edit the HTML, you can add the `data-priority="1"` attribute to the `th` element you want NOT to be hidden. Ex:

`<th data-priority="1">Last column</th>`